# Rails creating links to external sites with <%= link_to %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to send a user to a website such as www.facebook.com with a rails tag?

I tried:

```
<%= link_to www.facebook.com %>.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes,

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

```
<%= link_to 'facebook', 'https://www.facebook.com' %>
```

Comment: If you want to use an image for the button, then replace the 'facebook' with an image tag. i.e. <%= link_to image_tag('filename'), https://www.facebook.com %>